# How can I extract a percentage number without the "%" symbol from a string?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

```
-InternalBattery-0 (id=7405667) 100%; charged; 0:00 remaining present: true
```

I want to do `egrep -ow (regex)` on the above string and get only `100` of `100%` and nothing else. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to return the string representation of an integer between `0` and `100`, or only `"100"` (else no match)? If the latter is it sufficient to determine if `"100%"` is present? That is, why should it be necessary to return `"100"` if that's the only possible match?

Comment: Hey @CarySwoveland, Sorry I was not clear. 100% is my battery percentage so it will change. I want to extract that to use in my script.

Comment: @SACHINGURUSWAMY You can use pcregrep check my post below

Comment: It sounds that you wish to extract the digits that preceded `"%"` and those digits are the string representation of and integer between `0` and `100`.

Comment: Yes. exactly @car

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` with a backreferece to reinsert the digits before the percent sign in the general substitution form is probably a bit more doable than `grep`. For example you can use:

```
sed -E 's/^[^)]+\)\s+([0-9]+)%.*$/\1/'
```

Which matches one of more characters from the beginning that are not `')'`, then a literal `')'` and then matches any amount of whitespace. A capture group begins capturing digits up to the next `'%'` with remaining characters to end of line discarded. The first backreference `\1` is used to replace the whole line with what was captured between the `(...)` in `([0-9+)%`.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "-InternalBattery-0 (id=7405667) 100%; charged; 0:00 remaining present: true" | 
sed -E 's/^[^)]+\)\s+([0-9]+)%.*$/\1/'
100
```

**Awk Solution**

Since in the comment you mention you are attempting this in *Apple Script* (which I know little about), then perhaps a straight-forward `awk` solution that simply loops to find the field that contains the `'%'` character and than chops-off everything from `'%'` to the end of the field, prints the result and exits, e.g.

```
$ echo "-InternalBattery-0 (id=7405667) 100%; charged; 0:00 remaining present: true" | 
awk '{ for( i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /%/) { sub(/%.*$/,"",$i); print $i; exit }}'
100
```

That way you can, again, use the `'%'` character to identify the proper field in your string of text and then simply remove it, and anything that follows, and be confident that you have the correct result if `'%'` only appears once in your line of input.

Give it a try and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks alot @David. But it worked like a charm in ubuntu with sed and din't work in in mac. So I need something that works with grep since I need to store that value and use it to provide run over some condition check. it would be very helpful if I could get it using grep

Comment: Okay, give me a sec. I not sure what mac supports so I'll have to take a quick look.

Comment: @SACHINGURUSWAMY Can you give this a try on mac `sed 's/^[^)]*)[[:space:]][[:space:]]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)%.*$/\1/'` -- it is written using Basic Regular Expression syntax and POSIX `[:space:]` to match whitespace. Mac uses a BSD variant of `sed`, and even though they claim it is compatible with GNU and respects both `-E` and the alias `-r` for extended regex -- there are many instances where things just don't work the same...

Comment: Here is the link I was using (old, but updated) [Differences between sed on Mac OSX and other “standard” sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13711/197080)

Comment: Hey David. Thanks.
The following command returned me with 0 and 100. is there a way to ignore the first and get only the second may be ?
`echo "-InternalBattery-0 (id=7405667) 100%; charged; 0:00 remaining present: true" | egrep -ow '([0-9]{1,3})[^%]'`

Comment: Honestly, with `grep`, I would do it like `pct=$(echo "-InternalBattery-0 (id=7405667) 100%; charged; 0:00 remaining present: true" | egrep -ow '([0-9]{1,3})[%]'); echo ${pct:0: -1}` where you capture `100%` in a variable an chop off the `'%'`. (note: this works with bash -- if you are using zsh on mac, we may need to use POSIX `substr`) That is the pain with using `grep`, you have to use `'%'` to anchor the group of numbers you want. When you do `[^%]` you ignore that anchor.

Comment: makes sense. I am trying to use that in apple script which is weirder. I will try that and get back to you. thanks alot David.

Comment: One more: `echo "-InternalBattery-0 (id=7405667) 100%; charged; 0:00 remaining present: true" | awk '{ for( i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /%/) { sub(/%.*$/,"",$i); print $i; exit }}'`

Comment: There is always more than one way to *skin-the-cat* using shell `:)`

Comment: So true. it worked like a charm. Thanks alot David.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use 'grep' with '-P' option.

```
grep -Po '\d+(?=%)'
```

Comment: I have tried this as well but it gives me "grep: support for the -P option is not compiled into this --disable-perl-regexp binary". Do you know how can I fix this error?

Comment: Maybe your grep isn't supported with "-P" option.
You can do this way instead of "grep".
sed 's/^.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*\)%.*$/\1/'

Answer (score 0):

You can use pcregrep to check if the string has one to three digits preceded by a boundary and look ahead for a percentage character:

```
pcregrep --color '\b(?:100|[1-9]?\d)(?=%)' file.txt
```

To install pcreg you can download it from [here](https://pt.osdn.net/projects/sfnet_pcre/downloads/pcre/8.42/pcre-8.42.tar.gz/). To install it using macOS terminal check this [link](https://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/pcre/)

Comment: Thanks. it worked in regex101. but when used with `egrep` it threw the this error `egrep: repetition-operator operand invalid`

Comment: You need to use pcregrep I don’t know how to use lookahead with grep

Comment: I suggest a slight variant: `\b(?:100|\d{1,2})(?=%)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  yes that’s better.

Comment: @CarySwoveland to avoid 0x% as well we can do `\b(?:100|[1-9]?\d)(?=%)`